# How can I change items in tabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I created a custom bar but I can't change the location of the image and text in the itembar itself.

What I have:

[image]

and here is what I want to get:

[image]

How I initialize barItems:

```
private func initializeTabBar() {
    let mainNavigationController = MainNavigationController()
    mainNavigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Explorer", image: UIImage(named: "dot"), tag: 0)
 
    let mainCoordinator = coordinatorFactory.makeMainCoordinator(with: Router(rootController: mainNavigationController))
    
    let BasketViewController = BusketViewController()
    BasketViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "busket"), tag: 1)

    let FavoriteViewController = FavoriteViewController()
    FavoriteViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "heart"), tag: 2)
    
    let ProfileViewController = ProfileViewController()
    ProfileViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "profile"), tag: 3)
    
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [mainNavigationController,BasketViewController,FavoriteViewController,ProfileViewController]
```

tabbar setup:

```
func setup() {
    tabBar.itemWidth = tabBar.bounds.width / 10
    tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
    
    tabBar.tintColor = AppColors.white
    tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = AppColors.white
}

func setupBackground() {
    let positionX: CGFloat = 0
    let PositionY: CGFloat = 8
    let width = tabBar.bounds.width - positionX * 2
    let height = tabBar.bounds.height + PositionY * 2
    let rounderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(
        roundedRect: CGRect(x: positionX, y: tabBar.bounds.minY - PositionY, width: width, height: height), cornerRadius: height / 2 )
    rounderLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    rounderLayer.fillColor = AppColors.darkBlue.cgColor
    tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(rounderLayer, at: 0)
}
```

I will accept all advice or solutions.